# Why does WildFly not support javax packages during deployment

Tags: web, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm encountering an issue when deploying my web app to WildFly. It seems that WildFly does not support javax. Consequently, upon starting the app, I'm greeted with a 'forbidden' message on a blank page.

I'm relatively new to WildFly and debugging web apps. Could someone explain why WildFly doesn't support javax packages during deployment but supports jakarta? I'd appreciate guidance on how to debug this 'forbidden' issue, as I'm unsure where to start troubleshooting within WildFly.

I replaced javax to jakarta and that works okay.